# how to change log_reuse_wait and log_reuse_wait_desc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-backups, recovery, database-administration

I have been created new database and the log file groth very past, and I get error mesaage that the log is full due to 'BACKUP'.

I looked in the differences between this Database and other databases in the SERVER, and I seen that in all databases log_reuse_wait is 0 and log_reuse_wait_desc is NOTHING and in my database log_reuse_wait is 0 and log_reuse_wait_desc is LOG_BACKUP.

I want to change this property in my database to 0 and NOTHING.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution.
even the database is in `SIMPLE` mode is wait to `BACKUP_LOG`, so you need to change the recovery mode to `FULL` and then back to `SIMPLE` with `no wait`

```
USE [master] 
GO  
ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET RECOVERY full  
GO
ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
USE [db name]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE('<log file name>', 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a read-only status variable. It tells you why the log cannot be truncated at this point.

You have to remove the cause of that condition instead of just changing the value (which isn't even possible).

Either backup the database log or switch to `SIMPLE` recovery mode. You should probably read a little on both just to understand the implications.

Comment: thanks, my recovery mode was and is still `SIMPLE`. if i will backup the database log is not will occur again?

Answer (score 2):

David W.'s script did not quite work for me. (SQL Server 2008 r2)

I needed to modify it slightly. Using the script as is I got the message that there was no such file for database [master]. Alter the DATABASE as David W. recommends and then switch to the target database and run the `DBCC SHRINKFILE()` command.

Also the first argument to `DBCC SHRINKFILE()` must be the logical name of the database log file, which is represented in the following script as `logical_file_name_for_LOG`

```
USE [master] 
GO  
ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET RECOVERY full  
GO
ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
USE [db name]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE('<logical_file_name_for_LOG>', 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

Comment: i added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the answers are wrong.
If the database has recovery mode `FULL` and that is intended, then do not change it to `simple`.

The `log_reuse_wait_desc` says what the state is before the log can be reused or shrinked. In this case it is `LOG_BACKUP`, meaning that, to shrink the transaction log, you need to backup the transaction log first and shrink it or backup the log and let the SQLServer reuse the log space.

A description of the `log_reuse_wait_desc` states can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)