# Sql server on amazon RDS LogFile issue

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-rds, logfile

I have a Sql Server 2008 r2 Express instance on Amazon RDS with 30gb SSD. Storage space of this instance got filled today. In fact of that i decide to clean some soft-deleted rows from one of my databases. So i wrote my query on sql management studio and i'm getting that error.

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 1
>   The transaction log for database 'db_name' is full. To find out why space in the >log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

There are many databases on that instance and i'm facing that problem just in one db.

I have tried many different ways to solve the problem like below:

1. Tried to cleanup some storage deleting data from other databases
2. Tried to update log_reuse_wait_desc to NOTHING
3. Tried to change database config and shrink log file as mentioned on this post [how to change log_reuse_wait and log_reuse_wait_desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519125/how-to-change-log-reuse-wait-and-log-reuse-wait-desc)
4. Tried to change "tracefile retention"  to 0 using that query

   ```
   exec rdsadmin..rds_set_configuration 'tracefile retention',0;
   ```

Some of them run and some returns error but none of them is my solution.

Is there any way to unblock my database? It's really annoying, i can't do any operation than select data from this database!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of reading about MS SQL SERVER logging i found the source of the problem and the "Solution".

MS Sql server can't works without Logging but it give us enough modes to customize what kind of logging we want to have. You can find RECOVERY MODELS here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx.

Now i don't know the exact amount of storage per database which is available for logging on Amazon rds but if you ever face problems like this which i describe in my question you can use the bellow described scenario to face them.

**First Step (check your instance's db size)**

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
Name AS Logical_Name,
Physical_Name, (size*8)/1024 SizeMB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = ''?'' '
```

source: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/08/sql-server-find-the-size-of-database-file-find-the-size-of-log-file/

**Second Step (Set the desired Recovery Model)**

If you have already problem with your queries then the best way to solve them is to select SIMPLE recover model using a query like that.

```
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

> ATTENTION it's not the best model, it's the most "free" model. When you have >complete your job you have to choose the appropriate RECOVERY MODEL depended on >your project.

**Third Step (Shrink your logfiles)**

If you have select the Simple Recovery model in second step maybe already you have solve your problem and you are in position to execute your query but i'm suggesting you to shrink your logfiles. It's very easy to select the way to shrink your logfiles base on the manual here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx.

Bellow i'm give you as an example the code to find the logfile name and shrink it.

```
Declare @logName nvarchar(255)
SELECT @logName= name FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id = db_id() AND type = 1
DBCC SHRINKFILE(@logName, 250, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

**Conclusion**

As you can understand i'm far away from the real solution because it depends on Amazon RDS configuration but all my answer here is talking about a solution of the symptom and not about the solution of the real problem which has to do with the ways to maintain a database log file in normal size when your project needs to execute a big amount of queries (updates, deletes).